# how to split dataframe into equal number of subset in python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'user': [1, 1, 2,2,2,2 ,2,2,2,2], 'friends': 
[1,2,1,5,4,6,7,20,9,7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I try to split the `df` into several `n` pieces in a loop. For example, for `n=3`

```
n=3
for i in range(3):
   subdata = dosomething(df)
   print(subdata)
```

the output will be someting like

```
# first loop
   user friends
0   1   1
1   1   2
2   2   1
3   2   5

# second loop
   user friends
0   2   4
1   2   6
2   2   7
3   2   20 

#third loop
   user friends
0   2   9
1   2   7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use iloc and loop through the dataframe, put each new dataframe in a dictionary for recall later.

```
dfs = {}
chunk = 4
```

Loop through the dataframe by chunk sizes. Create df and add to dict.

```
for n in range((df.shape[0] // chunk + 1)):
    df_temp = df.iloc[n*chunk:(n+1)*chunk]
    df_temp = df_temp.reset_index(drop=True)
    dfs[n] = df_temp
```

Use this if statement for any left over rows at the end.

```
if df.shape[0] % chunk != 0:
    df_temp = df.iloc[-int(df.shape[0] % chunk):]
    df_temp = df_temp.reset_index(drop=True)
    dfs[n] = df_temp
else:
    pass
```

Access the dataframes in the dictionary.

```
print(dfs[0])

   user  friends
0     1        1
1     1        2
2     2        1
3     2        5

print(dfs[1])

   user  friends
0     2        4
1     2        6
2     2        7
3     2       20

print(dfs[2])

   user  friends
0     2        9
1     2        7
```